# how to do record count of .csv and attach that count with email processor to send anyone?

Tags: csv, bigdata, apache-nifi

What I tried so far is as follow:

[image: Nifi Flow for the record count]

kindly describe in details how many ways you can read .csv, what I learned so far you need to provide a schema name for the file and then define a schema in the form of .avro or text.
is it necessary to provide schema?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want the record count or do you want to do something else with the contents of the csv?

Answer (score 0):

`GetFile` -> `CalculateRecordStats` with CSV Reader. Then, you can get the `record.count` attribute without any settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CalculateRecordStats](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.CalculateRecordStats/index.html) processor to read your **CSV** based on provided schema/NiFi can get schema from header.

- CaluculateRecordStats processor adds **`records.count`** attribute to the flowfile.
- You can also add [user defined property](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.CalculateRecordStats/additionalDetails.html) then NiFi will user defined property filter counts to the flowfile also.

> **(or)**

Use [QueryRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/additionalDetails.html) processor and add new property with SQL query:

`select count(*) cnt from FLOWFILE`

- Define **`record reader/writer AVRO schema`** to get the count of records in the Flowfile.
- Then use [ExtractText](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-ExtractText-from-flow-file-using-Nifi-Processor/m-p/190828) processor to capture **`record count and keep as flowfile attribute.`**
- Use the extracted attribute value to include in your email.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from few great suggestions above, There is [`CountText`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.CountText/) processor which is simple enough if your csv is properly formatted and terminated with newlines. This processor will count the number of lines present in the incoming text. It provides attributes such as -

```
Name                        Description
text.line.count             The number of lines of text present in the FlowFile 
                            content

text.line.nonempty.count    The number of lines of text (with at least one non- 
                            whitespace character) present in the original 
                            FlowFile

text.word.count             The number of words present in the original 
                            FlowFile

text.character.count        The number of characters (given the specified 
                            character encoding) present in the original FlowFile
```

You can easily grab this attributes in `PutEmail` processors or even update the filename with count using expression language variables. For e.g use UpdateAttribute to update filename to `"FooBar_"${text.line.count}.csv`